Simple Injector: Best way to batch-register CQRSlite event handlers
In a project I am using CQRSlite and Simple Injector. My first try to register the event handlers:
    container.Register(typeof(ICancellableEventHandler<>), typeof(MaterialAddedToOperationHandler).Assembly);

This ended up in a HandlerNotResolvedException within CQSRlite. After a quick check I discovered that the CQRSlite RouteRegistrar is unfortunately requesting the concrete event handler types. So my registration above is useless and the only clean solution I found is registering every single one of them.
Having a bunch of event handlers I would prefer not to clutter my container initialization with all those single concrete type registrations.
My quick workaround is enabling the old handling of unregistered concrete types.
container.Options.ResolveUnregisteredConcreteTypes = true;

Understanding the idea behind this being disabled, I would prefer to keep it disabled.
What alternatives to register these event handlers do I have?

Check this part of the documentation. https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_GetTypesToRegister.htm

Checked it and it helped. If you write an answer, I will mark it
